# How does NextJS handle secure pages if tries to access them directly in the browser

Tags: html, reactjs, security, dom, next.js

How does NextJS handle secure pages when a user is not logged in and tries to access them directly in the browser?

Right now, I am trying to access the `/dashbaord` (a secure page). It's showing the dashboard DOM's, See the screenshot below.

[image: Dashboard HTML showing though I am not logged in, It redirects to login immediately.]

I am newbie to NextJS.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When successfully logged into the system, you can add some data to the browser's local storage. On the dashboard page, you need to check whether local storage has the value that you inserted when successfully logged, then the user can load that page, otherwise you can redirect to the login page.

On the login page, if the user enters the correct credentials, you need to set some values to local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem("login", "logged");
```

On the dashboard page, you need to check if the local storage has a session or not.

```
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  if(localStorage.getItem("login") !== "logged"){
    router.push('/login');
  }
}, []);
```

Note: This is not the appropriate method. Keep some tokens instead of the 'logged' value.

Comment: Seems that `middleware.js` approach is more appropriate to. Thanks for your answer <3